# Rails - delete method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to delete an entry as specified in the docs but I keep getting en error stating `NoMethodError in Tasks#show` and the entry is not deleted.

index.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', destroy_task_path(task['id']), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

route.rb:

```
delete '/tasks/:id', to: 'tasks#destroy', as: 'destroy_task'
resources :tasks
root 'home#index'
```

tasks_controller.rb

```
def destroy
  uri = URI.parse("http://localhost/tasks/public/api/tasks/"+params[:id])
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  request = Net::HTTP::Delete.new(uri.path)
  redirect_to :tasks, notice: 'Task was successfully destroyed.'
end
```

What am I doing wrong here?! and why does it get redirected to show?!

Answer (score 3):

You missed in your `link_to`call the `method: :delete`, otherwise you do a GET call.

Comment: What a clumsy mistake :/. Thank you